# Implementing a dynamic linked list without using struct for nodes

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm looking for advice about creating a very specific type of doubly linked linked list. This is not for an assignment. Each node is a C array of integer pointers.

```
Node Structure:
0: [back pointer "<-"]
1: [forward pointer "->"]
2: [data pointer "="]
```

Where the structure of the list is:

```
Linked List:

head->n0
n0[head<-][->n1][=10]
n1[n0<-][->n2][=11]
n2[n1<-][->tail][=12]
n2<-tail
```

How would I use stdlib's malloc() to create this structure in C?

Comment: Do you want to create the nodes one by one, or create the whole list with one call to `malloc` (and some assignments to variables)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a data node (struct datanode) that records the size and current length of the data array. We allow this array to grow dynamically, as you add elements. This solution splits the data array from the double-linked list node.

*Note: I omit 'struct' for brevity; fixing left as exercise for reader.*

```
/***
  Node Structure:
  0: [back pointer "<-"]
  1: [forward pointer "->"]
  2: [data pointer "="]
  Where the structure of the list is:

Linked List:
head->n0
n0[head<-][->n1][=10]
n1[n0<-][->n2][=11]
n2[n1<-][->tail][=12]
n2<-tail
 ***/

struct datanode {
    int size; // size of array allocated
    int len;  // number of elements assigned
    int ray[1]; // array[size], array[0..len] valid
};

datanode*
datanode_new(int size) {
    data_node* np = malloc( sizeof(data_node)+sizeof(int)*(size-1) );
    if( !np ) return(np);
    np->size = size;
    return(np)l
}
int
datanode_free(datanode* np) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    int size = np->size;
    free(np);
    return(size);
}
datanode*
datanode_resize(datanode* np, int size) {
    datanode* newp;
    if( !np ) {
        newp = datanode_new(size);
        return(newp);
    }
    if( size == np->size ) return(np); // no change
    newp = datanode_new(size);
    if( !newp ) return(np);
    for( int ndx = 0; ndx < min(size,np->len); ++ndx ) {
        newp->ray[ndx] = np->ray[ndx];
    }
    free(np);
    return(newp);
}
datanode*
datanode_copy(datanode* np, datanode* dp) {
    datanode* newp=NULL;
    if( !np ) return(dp);
    if( !dp ) return(dp);
    for( int ndx = 0; ndx < min(dp->size,np->len); ++ndx ) {
        dp->ray[ndx] = np->ray[ndx];
    }
    return(newp);
}
datanode*
datanode_dup(datanode* np) {
    datanode* newp=NULL;
    if( !np ) return(newp);
    newp = datanode_new(np->size);
    if( !newp ) return(newp);
    datanode_copy(np, newp);
    return(newp);
}
int
datanode_size(datanode* np) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    return(np->size);
}
int
datanode_set(datanode* np, unsigned int index,int val) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    if( index <= np->size ) { np->ray[index] = val; }
    return(index);
}
// autoexpand (double when reach capacity)
int
datanode_add(datanode* np,int val) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    if( np->len >= np->size ) {
        datanode* newp = datanode_resize(np->size*2);
    }
    int len = np->len;
    if( np->len < np->size ) {
        np->ray[np->len++] = val;
        return(len);
    }
    else { return(-1); }
    return(len);
}
int
datanode_valid(datanode* np, unsigned int index) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    if( index <= np->len ) return(0);
    return(-1);
}
int
datanode_at(datanode* np, unsigned int index) {
    if( !np ) return(-1);
    if( index <= np->len ) return(np->ray[index]);
    return(-1);
}
```

Then you need a double-linked list node; the parent pointer is used to provide a mechanism to detect head/tail and provide head/tail structure maintenance.

```
struct my_dnode {
    my_dnode* prev;
    my_dnode* next;
    void* parent;   //not NULL when head or tail
    datanode* data;
};

my_dnode*
mydnode_new(int size) {
    my_dnode* dn = malloc( sizeof(my_dnode) );
    if( !dn ) return(ln);
    dn->prev = NULL;
    dn->next = NULL;
    dn->parent = NULL;
    dn->data = datanode_new(size);
    return(dn);
}
// only reasonable to delete node once removed from list
my_dnode*
mydnode_free(my_dnode* dn) {
    if( !dn ) return(dn);
    if( dn->prev ) return(dn->prev);
    if( dn->next ) return(dn->next);
    if( dn->data ) {
        datanode_clear(dn->data);
        datanode_free(dn->data);
        dn->data = NULL;
    }
    return(ln);
}
my_dnode*
mydnode_prev(my_dnode* np) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    return(np->prev);
}
my_dnode*
mydnode_next(my_dnode* np) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    return(np->next);
}
// after after current node np, append node xp
my_dnode*
mydnode_append(my_dnode* np, my_dnode* xp) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    if( !xp ) return(xp);
    xp->next = np->next;
    xp->prev = np;
    if( np->next ) { np->next->prev = xp; }
    np->next = xp;
    // if( np->parent ) { need to fix tail }
    return(xp);
}
// before current node np, insert node xp
my_dnode*
mydnode_insert(my_dnode* np, my_dnode* xp) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    if( !xp ) return(xp);
    xp->prev = np->prev;
    xp->next = np;
    if( np->prev ) { np->prev->next = xp; }
    np->prev = xp;
    // if( np->parent ) { need to fix head }
    return(xp);
}
// extract node xp at current node np
my_dnode*
mydnode_extract(my_dnode* np) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    my_dnode* xp = np; // extract node
    // if( xp->parent ) { need to fix head or tail }
    if( np->prev ) { np->prev->next = np->next; }
    if( np->next ) { np->next->prev = xp->prev; }
    xp->next = NULL;
    xp->prev = NULL;
    return(xp);
}
// drop next node after current node np
my_dnode*
mydnode_drop(my_dnode* np, my_dnode* xp) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    if( np->next ) { return(mydnode_extract(np->next); }
    my_dnode* xp = np; // this node
    return(mydnode_extract(xp));
}
// pop previous node before current node
my_dnode*
mydnode_pop(my_dnode* np, my_dnode* xp) {
    if( !np ) return(np);
    if( np->prev ) { return(mydnode_extract(np->prev); }
    my_dnode* xp = np; // extract node
    return(mydnode_extract(xp));
}
```

You (may) want a parent list structure that holds the head & tail of the list, to ease tracking of list structure.

```
struct my_dlist {
    my_dnode* head;
    my_dnode* tail;
    int size; //default size
    int val;  //default value
};

my_dlist*
dlist_new(int size, int value) {
    my_dlist dp = malloc( sizeof(my_dlist) );
    if( !dp ) return(dp);
    dp->head = NULL;
    dp->tail = NULL;
    dp->size = size;
    dp->val = value;
    return(dp);
}
int
dlist_del( my_dlist* dp, int size, int value) {
    if( !dp ) return(-1);
    if( dp->head ) return(-2); //error
    if( dp->tail ) return(-3); //error
    dp->size = 0;
    dp->val = 0;
    return(0);
}
int
ln_append(my_dlist* dp, datanode* np) {
    if( !dp ) return(-1);
    if( !np ) return(-2);
    np->prev = dp->tail;
    dp->tail = np;
    // if( np->parent ) { need to fix tail }
    return(0);
}
int
ln_insert(my_dlist* dp, datanode* np) {
    if( !dp ) return(-1);
    if( !np ) return(-2);
    np->next = dp->head;
    dp->head = np;
    // if( np->parent ) { need to fix head }
    return(0);
}
datanode*
ln_head(my_dlist* dp) {
    if(!dp) return(NULL);
    return(dp->head);
}
datanode*
ln_tail(my_dlist* dp) {
    if(!dp) return(NULL);
    return(dp->tail);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, however my goal was to implement a node using an array rather than a stuct. Each node would be a static array of three int pointers, a block of 24 bytes in memory; such that the components of each node could be accessed using [0]-[2] with another pointer acting as an accessor. Then I'd like to dynamically allocate these nodes. Is this achievable, or am I reinventing the wheel and this is why Dennis included structs in C?